# Unable to compile AIR app from command line

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I have built an AIR app with a simple native extension that exposes APIs to control the volume of the device. My current target platform is iOS for the iPad. The project is based upon the tutorial at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html by Nathan Weber.

While the binary compiles correctly through the Flash Builder interface, I simply cannot get it to work from the command line. This is essential for us in order to integrate with our automated build process. I tried everything right up to finding the exact Java process command line that Flash Builder triggers internally in order to execute the compilation process, then running the exact same command manually through a Terminal window. The command and the result are pasted below.

```
bin-debug pranav.negandhi$ /usr/bin/java -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -jar '/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/sdks/4.6.0 copy/lib/adt.jar' -package -target ipa-ad-hoc -provisioning-profile '/Users/pranav.negandhi/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/ne-client/certs/clientdev.mobileprovision' -storetype pkcs12 -keystore '/Users/pranav.negandhi/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/ne-client/certs/danapaniCertificate2013.p12' -storepass danapani2013 Main.ipa Main-app.xml Main.swf splash.jpg -extdir '/Users/pranav.negandhi/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui/ANEFiles/ne-client/com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.ios.platform' -platformsdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk

ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _llvm_unwind from AOTBuildOutput-0.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
ld: warning: multiple L$start$ labels found at same address in __ZN9NetStream12DispatchProcEP10NativeInfo at offset 0x06C0
```

Ignoring the warnings doesn't work, as the resulting IPA never installs onto the iPad. When I sync the device through iTunes, the installation on the iPad fails with a brief "Main-debug failed to install" message.

The same code, native extensions and configuration files are used in Flash Builder.

I'd be glad for some pointers to begin solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was a mismatch with the application identifier in the application descriptor. I can't understand how it worked through Flash Builder but didn't when using the command line.

I still get the same warnings listed above, but they do not affect the application installation.

For those new to iOS development, especially those not using Apple's toolchain, start using the Organizer feature in Xcode instead of installing the app binary through iTunes. It provides more verbose and sensible error messages, plus several other features such as logs and a real time console. I'd have never found the problem if not for this.